# How to launch my other application or default application?

Tags: android

How to launch my other application or default application (like keyboard) in button click event?  I want  open other applications in my custom application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use below code in the event of your button action:

com.package.address == other application or default application's packages name

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Happy coding !!!